# when creating package from .Net Core project but changes to the project is not reflected in the updated package

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Using dotnt pack to pack the project dll as nuget package which can be consumed in any other project. first time it is working fine but when you make changes to the project and update the package then the dll packed is not having changes made.

if the dll is referenced separately then the changes are reflected but when packed then it is not having the changes.
Nuget is not referencing the latest dll while packing it.